# Removing empty spaces between bars in faceted barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I have a plot like this, made from:

```
plot = ggplot(dat, aes(x=Nest)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=MotherID), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) + facet_wrap(~Year) + scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + theme(legend.position="none") + ylab("Number of offpsring")
```

I'd like all the bars to be next to each other without the gaps between them at like 3, 4, 9 on the x axis. I guess it is because nest is a number rather than a string.

I have `dat$nest = as.factor(dat$nest)`

Comment: Assuming you turned `nest` into a factor before plotting, does `facet_wrap(~ Year, scales="free_x",  space="free_x")` resolve your issue?

Comment: yes, thanks, but I only needed the scales="free_x" bit :)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use facets, the axes are shared between them. However the `scales` argument can set them free.

```
facet_wrap(~Year, scales = "free_x")
```

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html